# ANdroid studio debuger : AndroidManifest.xml:11: AAPT: error: unexpected element <users-sdk> found in <manifest>

Tags: android, android-studio

install androd studio compile and show error:

ERROR:D:\Proyectos\Android\ScanerBar\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

[the mainfest original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF4JN.jpg)

[and mainfest debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxxI3.jpg)

how to fix the problem in comipiler?

i am implementing read barcode with library:
zxing-android-embedded

show error, not get solution with the problem
[this error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksL3k.jpg)

Comment: How about learning to spell properly? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-sdk>` has no r in it.

Remove the r from your tag.